# CodePen not showing any ReactJS component

Tags: reactjs, codepen

**HTML**

```
<div id="p1"> </div>
```

**JS (Babel)**

```
function MyFunct () {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Tanzeel</h1>
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(< MyFunct />, document.querySelector('#p1'));
```

I've also included both the CDNs.
**1) React**
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js

**2) ReactDOM**
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js

**3) JavaScript Preprocessor**
Babel

**4) Code Pen**
Click [here](https://codepen.io/CodingMonk/pen/gBrPMv)

Comment: ReactDOM cdn library not loaded successfully. If you look at console then it throws error `Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined`.

Comment: use these cdn links instead: https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 16.4.2 version of ReactDOM instead so it matches your React version, I had same issue so not your fault:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js